# Google Colab not making use of its GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I'm using keras with tensorflow on google colab with hardware accelerator set to 'GPU'. I checked and GPU is configured.

```
Found GPU at: /device:GPU:0
```

But still, when I run the code, it's taking a lot of time and GPU usage is also close to none and CPU is being used most of the time.
Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please share a notebook that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Here's the link to the notebook : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1euj_e43US14ADfRTI3t1cbcOD7Vvsizp

Comment: @BobSmith,please check it out